# refining colors on GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: geographics

Here is the code I am using to get an image of the entire USA.

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "USStates"][
  All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #ConfirmedCases[
         "LastValue"]} &]; GeoRegionValuePlot[data]
GeoRegionValuePlot[data]
```

How do I temporarily remove Alaska and Hawaii?
How do I make it so that the colorfunction will have at least six colors with adequately many bins for the states with low incidence of covid-19?  TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To remove Alaska and Hawaii:

**1.** Use `GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "DefaultMapArea"]` as the option value for `GeoRange`:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[data, 
 GeoRange -> GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "DefaultMapArea"]]
```

[image]

**2.** Filter `data` to select the continental states:

```
continentalus = EntityList @ Interpreter["USStateClass"]["Continental US"];

cdata = Select[MemberQ[continentalus, #[[1]]] &]@data;

assoc = AssociationThread @@ Transpose[cdata];

GeoRegionValuePlot[assoc]
```

[image]

#### To *refine* colors:

**1.** Use the option `PlotRange` to use all the color contrast for the states with confirmed cases between `min` and `max`:

```
{min, max} = {0, 50000};

GeoRegionValuePlot[assoc, 
 GeoRange -> GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "DefaultMapArea"], 
 PlotRange -> {min, max, Automatic}]
```

[image]

**2.** Define a piece-wise color function using a list of bin limits of your choice:

```
binlims = {0, 2000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 25000, 50000, 200000, 1000000};

colorF = Function[x, 
   Piecewise[Transpose[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, Length[#] - 1}}] /@ 
         Range[0, Length[#] - 1], #}] & @
     BlockMap[#[[1]] <= x < #[[2]] &, binlims, 2, 1], Black]];

Legended[GeoRegionValuePlot[Map[colorF] @ assoc, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.7]]], 
 SwatchLegend[colorF /@ binlims, BlockMap[Row[#, " - "] &, binlims, 2, 1]]]
```

[image]

**Aside:** You can also use `GeoHistogram` using state polygons as bins and `Values[assoc]` as *height* values:

```
GeoHistogram[assoc, Polygon /@ Keys[assoc], Values[assoc] &, 
 ColorFunction -> colorF, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[colorF /@ binlims, 
   BlockMap[Row[#, " - "] &, binlims, 2, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Super.  I was wondering if you could give me some insight into my other question, "How do I make it so that the colorfunction will have at least six colors with adequately many bins for the states with low incidence of covid-19"?